# Chamar um método da classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, método

Como posso exibir o método dessa classe revista na classe Teste?

```
public interface Produto {

    void exibirNome(String nome);
}

public class Revista  implements Produto {

    @Override
    public void exibirNome(String nome) {

        System.out.println("Exibindo revista de nome: " + nome);

    }


}


public class Teste {

    private Produto produto;
    String nome;

    public Teste(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;

    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        //Aqui eu gostaria de passar o método exibirNome da classe Revista
    }

}
```

E passar no toString();

```
Produto p = new Revista();
        Teste teste = new Teste(p);

        System.out.println(teste); //para exibir a revista
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Eu fiz funcionar:

```
interface Produto {
    void exibirNome(String nome);
}
 
class Revista implements Produto {
    @Override
    public void exibirNome(String nome) {
        System.out.println("Exibindo revista de nome: " + nome);
    }
}
 
class Teste {
    private Produto produto;
    String nome;
 
    public Teste(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }
 
    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        produto.exibirNome(nome);
        return nome;
    }
}
 
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Produto p = new Revista();
        Teste teste = new Teste(p);
        System.out.println(teste);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iHThml). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gxkvszcw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/MultipleErrors.java).

**Mas esse código não faz o menor sentido**. Até pensei em reescrever de um jeito melhor, mas não achei como, de tão sem sentido que ele é. Pra deixar certo teria que mudar tanto que seria outra coisa completamente diferente.

Essa interface não faz sentido, essa assinatura induz à implementação ruim, a implementação desse método na classe não faz sentido, usá-lo dentro do `toString()` não faz sentido, a classe `Teste` não tem sentido, tem essa propriedade `nome` que não é usada de fato, até porque ela está avulsa aí, e por aí vai...

Comment: `class HelloWorld`? Não dava para botar um nome melhor?

Comment: Além disso, este código vai acabar por exibir o nome duas vezes, uma no `main` e outra dentro do `toString()`, e provavelmente não seria esse o objetivo (e se for, há formas muito melhores de se chegar nele). E também, não é clara qual é a finalidade ou a motivação de instanciar-se um `Teste` ou o que uma instância disso significa.

Comment: "*a classe usuário não tem sentido*" - Acho você quis dizer outra coisa. A que você se refere? (A) A classe `Produto`; (B) A classe `Teste`; (C) A classe que usa essas duas coisas juntas (`HelloWorld`); (D) Todas as alternativas anteriores.

Comment: @VictorStafusa dá um trabalho pra usar outro nome no CodingGround. Esse código tem algum objetivo? Vamos combinar que não faz sentido fazer nada disso. Arrumei o texto.

Comment: Sim esse código tem um objetivo: Servir como um exemplo puro, perfeito e legítimo do uso de Programação Desorientada a Objetos. 

Comment: @VictorStafusa nesse ponto eu concordo :)

Answer (score 3):

Seguindo os princípios da `Herança` e do `Polimorfismo`, sua classe `Revista` implementa a interface `Produto` e portanto seus métodos abstratos. Deste modo, em sua classe `Teste` que tem um produto, basta você fazer a seguinte chamada.

```
produto.exibirNome();
```

Assim o atributo `produto` da classe `Teste` que é uma `Revista`, irá se comportar seguindo a implementação do método da classe Revista. Isso é conhecido como polimorfismo. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public interface Animal {  
    public void fala();
}


public class Homem implements Animal{

    @Override
    public void fala() {
        System.out.println("Olá Mundo!");
    }
}

public class Gato implements Animal{

    @Override
    public void fala() {
        System.out.println("Miau!");
    }    
}

public class Polimorfismo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal homem = new Homem();
        Animal gato = new Gato();

        homem.fala();
        gato.fala();
    }

}
```

Que tem como saída

```
Olá Mundo!
Miau!
```

OBS: Para chegar no efeito que acredito que vc deseja sugiro colocar uma atributo `String` nome na classe `Revista` e modificar o método

> `public void exibirNome(String nome)`

para

```
public void exibirNome()
```

Ficando assim parte do código final

```
    public interface Produto {

    void exibirNome();
}

public class Revista  implements Produto {
    String nome;
    @Override
    public void exibirNome() {
            System.out.println("Exibindo revista de nome: " + nome);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse seu formato, para chamar um método dentro de qualquer outra classe é necessário você fazer desta forma:

```
new Revista().exibirNome("Mah oi!");
```

Sugiro você dar uma lida em [Modificadores de acesso do Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/modificadores-de-acesso-do-java/25404) para aumentar seus conhecimentos.